# Why is ListDensityPlot unable to plot datasets with extreme ranges

Tags: graphics, plotting, graphics3d

Consider the following dataset:

```
data = Flatten[
 Table[{x 10^-9, y 10^-9, x^2 + y^2},{x, -100, 100, 10}, {y, -100,100, 10}]
 , 1];
```

If I try to `ListDensityPlot` this set:

```
ListDensityPlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

it does not plot the function. However, if I do the obvious re-scale of the coordinates:

```
data2 = Flatten[Table[{x , y , x^2 + y^2}, {x, -100, 100, 10}, {y, -100, 100, 10}], 1];
```

it has no problem plotting it:

```
ListDensityPlot[data2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same problem exists for other plotting methods (`ListPlot3D`, `ListContourPlot`, etc.). While rescaling the coordinates is a simple fix, is it possible to plot datasets of this sort without first rescaling the coordinates?

Comment: `ListDensityPlot[data]` works fine in V12.2.  At some point in the last nine years, this must have been fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why `ListDensityPlot` doesn't plot it is because the meshes aren't being generated correctly:

```
ListDensityPlot[data #, Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {1, 100, 10^3, 10^4}
```

[image]

Now I don't know exactly how to fix this, but my guess is that the mesh function relies on the Delaunay triangulation of the set of points and somewhere in there, something is either dangerously close to machine precision or getting `Chop`ped. Since the default tolerance for chopping is $10^{-10}$, it is plausible that this is what is happening.

Comment: Very interesting. Your point about the meshing seems to be correct. The mesh seems to converge to a stable sort of version with scaling here ~`10^8`.

Comment: @EliLansey Also, the mesh depends on the order the points in the original data, suggesting that it might be a naïve incremental triangulation. To see what I mean, try `ListDensityPlot[RandomSample[data, 441] #, Mesh -> All, 
   ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {1, 100, 10^3, 10^4}`

Comment: if you add MaxPlotPoints -> 20 then last 2 graphs are fine... and MaxPlotPoints -> 10 then 3rd graph is fine but not 4th.

Comment: The ListDensityPlot works with Graphics options and primitives are converted to integer somewhere as you said it chops the data so does the ListPlot3D... And with graphics it has no option for accuracy like some other plots.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the

```
DataRange->{{Subscript[x, min],Subscript[x, max]},{Subscript[y, min],Subscript[y, max]}}
```

which specifies other ranges of coordinate values to use. By default it uses the Automatic values...
e.g.

```
ListDensityPlot[data, DataRange -> {{-100, 100}, {-10^-9, 10^-9}}]
```

Comment: I think you mean `DataRange -> {{-10^-7, 10^-7}, {-10^-7, 10^-7}}`. This works because using `Datarange` makes `ListDensityPlot` completely ignore the x and y values.

Comment: I didn't test if the ranges are correct. Just tried to give an example. But it was working. May be you are right. I'll check...

Comment: This doesn't work. This is helpful if you have an array of values like `Table[x^2 + y^2, {x, -100, 100, 10}, {y, -100, 100, 10}]`, but here I have the x and y values given.

Comment: yep, both of you are right and same problem exist for ListPlot3D too. Some how it's related to precision  10^-5 works but not 10^-9...

Comment: `DataRange` does not work correctly for this problem on version 7.  The plot comes out mangled:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl5NY.png

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I get the same thing with `DataRange` on V8. Note, that's only if the `x` and `y` coordinates are specified, and it's not an array, where `DataRange` works as expected.

Comment: I think it's not version problem... In general, the solution I provided is problematic and it doesn't work.

Comment: @s.s.o Why not delete it in that case?