# White spots in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, interpolation

I have a problem with `ListDensityPlot`.
I have some [data](http://ge.tt/8oL9E48/v/7?c) on an irregular grid.

I try to plot them with

```
xStart=0;
xEnd=1000;
yStart=170;
yEnd=270;
ListDensityPlot[data,PlotRange -> {{xStart, xEnd}, {yStart, yEnd}}, FrameTicks -> True, 
AspectRatio -> Abs[(yEnd - yStart)/(xEnd - xStart)], PlotRangePadding -> None,   
ColorFunction -> (If[#1 === 0 , Black, GrayLevel[Rescale[#1, {0, 1}]]] &), 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, LightingAngle -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

In the output I have some ugly white spots:
[image: picture with white spots]

If I change my plot (setting `xEnd = 230`), the white spots disappear:
[image: picture with reduced range]

So, from my point of view, the white spots are not caused by my data. Somehow Mathematica (I am using 9.0.1) causes them.

To solve this problem I am using the following workaround:

```
ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> {{xStart, xEnd/1}, {yStart, yEnd}, All}, 
BoxRatios -> {1, Abs[(yEnd - yStart)/(xEnd - xStart)], 1}, 
ColorFunction -> (If[#1 === 0 , Black, GrayLevel[Rescale[#3, {0, 1}]]] &), 
ColorFunctionScaling -> True,Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> 1500, 
ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

This gives me a nice output:
[image: picture without white spots]

What can I do that I get the same output with `ListDensityPlot`? At least I need `ListDensityPlot` because changes in the `InterpolationOrder` look there different than in the `ListPlot3D`.

There is perhaps a similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4375/why-is-listdensityplot-unable-to-plot-datasets-with-extreme-ranges), but rescaling does not help here. Additionally, my problem is “solved” with `ListPlot3D`, Eli Lansey’s problem not.

I would be happy about some help!

Comment: Looks like it might be clipping.  Try `PlotRange -> {{xStart, xEnd}, {yStart, yEnd}, All}`

Comment: 1000 scores for you!! This is the solution! Please type this as answer, so that I can give you at least one score!
How shall somebody have the idea to use 3 options in `PlotRange` for a 2-dimensional plot? As far as I know there is nothing about this trick in the help about `ListDensityPlot`. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14260/white-regions-in-densityplot-is-this-a-bug-with-colorfunctionscaling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The white generally indicates plot range clipping.  See [ListDensityPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListDensityPlot.html), the [ClippingStyle](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListDensityPlot.html#1429346778) and [PlotRange](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListDensityPlot.html#90583055) sections.

Setting

```
PlotRange -> {{xStart, xEnd}, {yStart, yEnd}, All}
```

will include all data values.  If the data has a few extreme values, including the whole range will flatten out smaller variations in the data.

Comment: Thanks again for this solution. I know `ClippingStyle`, but that you can get rid of this feature by your trick is new for me. Actually, this trick should be mentioned in Mathematica`s help (or I have overseen it). Anyway, you helped me a lot!

Comment: @partial81 I think the examples in the "PlotRange" section (under "Options") of `ListDensityPlot` is trying to show this trick.  I admit that at first glance, it's hard to see because the default color scheme ends at "white."  Try them with `ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"`.  (Also I mistyped the link in my answer -- fixed now.)

Comment: You are right! And this trick is well hidden. Thanks for the fix and the explanation!