# Dataset seems unable to handle ListDensityPlot and ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, version-10, dataset

If I create a `Dataset`:

```
dataSet = Dataset[
  AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"} -> #] & /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 5}]
];
```

It should be easy to use a plotting function on it

```
dataSet[ListContourPlot, {"a", "e", "c"}]
```

but all I get is the list of associations back.

Why does `Dataset` not plot my data query?

I don't understand why this happens, since if I replace `ListContourPlot` with, say `ListPointPlot3D` (these functions work on lists of triplets), it works fine. `ListDensityPlot` has the same problem. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with [extreme ranges in my dataset](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4375/why-is-listdensityplot-unable-to-plot-datasets-with-extreme-ranges), and I can't see anything wrong with the dataset itself; i.e., the following works fine:

```
With[{
  t = {
    Normal @ dataSet[All, "a"],
    Normal @ dataSet[All, "e"],
    Normal @ dataSet[All, "c"]
    }
  },
  ListContourPlot[Transpose[t]]]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you want is the following:

```
dataSet[ListContourPlot, {#a, #e, #c} &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
dataSet[ListDensityPlot, {#a, #e, #c} &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you still want to use the `Keys` directly then you'll have to force `ListContourPlot` and `ListDensityPlot` to extract only the `Values` as follows:

```
dataSet[ListContourPlot[Values@#] &, {"a", "e", "c"}]
```

Comment: @gpap That's what it looks like. I bet what's happening is that `ListPointPlot3D` was updated to work with `Association`s whereas `ListContourPlot` and `ListDensityPlot` weren't.

Answer (score 6):

The problem does not lie with `Dataset`, but rather with `ListContourPlot`:

```
$data =
  { <|"a"->0.846,"e"->0.770,"c"->0.682|>
  , <|"a"->0.211,"e"->-0.434,"c"->0.944|>
  , <|"a"->0.716,"e"->0.171,"c"->0.529|>
  };

ListContourPlot @ $data

(* ListContourPlot[{ <|a->0.846,e->0.77,c->0.682|>,
     <|a->0.211,e->-0.434,c->0.944|>,<|a->0.716,e->0.171,c->0.529|>}] *)
```

The result is inert, showing that `ListContourPlot` does not operate upon associations.  It is necessary to explicitly extract the values:

```
ListContourPlot @ Values @ $data
```

[image: contour plot screenshot]

`ListPointPlot3D`, by contrast, *does* operate upon associations:

```
ListPointPlot3D @ $data
```

[image: 3D plot screenshot]

The documentation for `ListPointPlot3D` makes no mention of this capability.

The [documentation for Association](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) says...

> *Typical list operations (such as Map, Select, and Sort) apply to the values in an association, leaving the keys unchanged.*

... and ...

> *Keys are "transparent" for many operations*

... but it remains silent on the identity of those "many operations" beyond a few examples.  Apparently `ListPointPlot3D` is one of those operations, but `ListContourPlot` is not.  Perhaps it is rather that the *internal implementation* of `ListPointPlot3D` uses one of those "many operations", but the implementation of `ListContourPlot` does not.

So, for the moment at least, we must learn the set of "many operations" by experimentation.

**Edit**

Note that `Dataset` already has up-value wrapper definitions for many operators, including `ListContourPlot`.  WRI certainly has the option of adjusting the wrapper definition of `Dataset` instead of making `ListContourPlot` handle associations, although the latter would seem to have more general applicability.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer - I accepted the one that was offered first but yours is equally illuminating (I have upvoted). I was just surprised that it worked with one plotting function and not another seeing as the input they take is pretty much the same (list of triplets).

Answer (score 5):

I can't quite wrap my head around what a `Dataset` is, and why it **does** work with `ListPointPlot3D`.  But as a workaround you can just use

```
dataSet[ListDensityPlot[{"a","e","c"}/.#]&,{"a","e","c"}]
```

and

```
dataSet[ListContourPlot[{"a","e","c"}/.#]&,{"a","e","c"}]
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason I am asking is 'cause I am trying to understand how datasets work too. I think your workaround is more shorthand than anything I've used so far (so +1) but I am actually interested in the why so I'll wait to get a bit more insight on that

Comment: The `FullForm` of a `Dataset` shows a data part and the internal data structure spec. Sounds like Although it may change in future revs, current `Dataset`,  `Query` etc are specialized interfaces unlike generic M code.