# Mathematical operation on two lists by a "key"

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm a complete newb here.  Just looking for direction.  I've got two lists like this...

```
list1 = {{{2014, 9, 2}, 4.18}, {{2014, 9, 3}, 4.17}, {{2014, 9, 4}, 4.18}, {{2014, 9, 5}, 
    4.17}, {{2014, 9, 8}, 4.13}, {{2014, 9, 9}, 4.15}, {{2014, 9, 10}, 
    4.08}, {{2014, 9, 11}, 4.03}, {{2014, 9, 12}, 4.06}, {{2014, 9, 15}, 
    3.98}, {{2014, 9, 16}, 3.89}, {{2014, 9, 17}, 3.82}, {{2014, 9, 18}, 
    3.88}, {{2014, 9, 19}, 3.93}, {{2014, 9, 22}, 3.81}, {{2014, 9, 23}, 
    3.76}, {{2014, 9, 24}, 3.71}, {{2014, 9, 25}, 3.7}, {{2014, 9, 26}, 
    3.63}, {{2014, 9, 29}, 3.56}, {{2014, 9, 30}, 3.56}, {{2014, 10, 1}, 
    3.39}, {{2014, 10, 2}, 3.37}, {{2014, 10, 3}, 3.43}, {{2014, 10, 6}, 
    3.42}, {{2014, 10, 7}, 3.35}, {{2014, 10, 8}, 3.3}, {{2014, 10, 9}, 
    3.03}, {{2014, 10, 10}, 2.95}, {{2014, 10, 13}, 2.78}, {{2014, 10, 14}, 
    2.61}, {{2014, 10, 15}, 2.62}, {{2014, 10, 16}, 2.56}, {{2014, 10, 17}, 2.67}};

list2 = {{{2014, 9, 2}, 4.16}, {{2014, 9, 3}, 4.19}, {{2014, 9, 4}, 4.15}, {{2014, 9, 5}, 
   4.15}, {{2014, 9, 8}, 4.13}, {{2014, 9, 9}, 4.08}, {{2014, 9, 10}, 
   4.08}, {{2014, 9, 11}, 4.08}, {{2014, 9, 12}, 3.96}, {{2014, 9, 15}, 
   3.91}, {{2014, 9, 16}, 3.81}, {{2014, 9, 17}, 3.82}, {{2014, 9, 18}, 
   3.88}, {{2014, 9, 19}, 3.81}, {{2014, 9, 22}, 3.76}, {{2014, 9, 23}, 
   3.69}, {{2014, 9, 24}, 3.7}, {{2014, 9, 25}, 3.63}, {{2014, 9, 26}, 
   3.6}, {{2014, 9, 29}, 3.55}, {{2014, 9, 30}, 3.41}, {{2014, 10, 1}, 
   3.35}, {{2014, 10, 2}, 3.39}, {{2014, 10, 3}, 3.4}, {{2014, 10, 6}, 
   3.36}, {{2014, 10, 7}, 3.28}, {{2014, 10, 8}, 3.28}, {{2014, 10, 9}, 
   2.95}, {{2014, 10, 10}, 2.72}, {{2014, 10, 13}, 2.74}, {{2014, 10, 14}, 
   2.62}, {{2014, 10, 15}, 2.61}, {{2014, 10, 16}, 2.64}, {{2014, 10, 17}, 2.72}};
```

How can I subtract (or perform any operation on) list one values from list two values using the date as the 'key'?  The resulting list would have a dates and the result from the operation on list one and list two.  In other words, with the example lists above, the output value would start with `{{{2014,9,2},-0.02},...`

Thanks in advance

Comment: First a question for you: are you using version 10?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard FWIW, do you know if there is some indicator provided by the site that the page is being edited?  You beat me by a few seconds, and it would be helpful to know that someone is already working on edits.

Comment: @bobthechemist Sadly, no.  I've had that happen to me quite a few times too.  Perhaps you should propose something on http://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm actually using the wolfram language.  Is that version 10 of mathematica ?

Answer (score 6):

If you have version 10 with [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) and related functionality, and if all keys are present in both:

```
<|Rule @@@ list2|> - <|Rule @@@ list1|>
```

> ```
> <|{2014, 9, 2} -> -0.02, {2014, 9, 3} -> 0.02, ... {2014, 10, 17} -> 0.05|>
> ```

See: [Listable functions thread over Associations; is this documented?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63293/121)

If some keys are missing from one list or the other you could start with [`KeyIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyIntersection.html):

```
Subtract @@ KeyIntersection[{Rule @@@ list2, Rule @@@ list1}]
```

For earlier versions assuming no key is duplicated with a single list:

```
Cases[Join[list2, list1] ~GatherBy~ First, {{d_, n2_}, {_, n1_}} :> {d, n2 - n1}]
```

> ```
> {{{2014, 9, 2}, -0.02}, {{2014, 9, 3}, 0.02}, ... {{2014, 10, 17}, 0.05}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

If you have version 10 you can also use

```
List@@@Normal@GroupBy[Join[list1,list2],First->Last,#[[2]]-#[[1]]&]
```

> ```
>   {{{2014,9,2},-0.02},{{2014,9,3},0.02},{{2014,9,4},-0.03},{{2014,9,5},-0.02},
>     {{2014,9,8},0.},{{2014,9,9},-0.07},{{2014,9,10},0.},{{2014,9,11},0.05},
>     ... 
>     {{2014,10,16},0.08},{{2014,10,17},0.05}}
> ```

For version 9

```
{#[[1,1]],#[[All,2]][[2]]-#[[All,2]][[1]]}&/@GatherBy[Join[list1,list2],First]
```

or

```
{#[[1,1]],Subtract@@Reverse[#[[All,2]]]}&/@GatherBy[Join[list1,list2],First]
```

gives the same result.