# ReplaceAll with Associations instead of Rules

Tags: replacement, core-language, associations, rule

I have just noticed that

```
x /. <|x -> 123|>
```

evaluates to

```
123
```

In other words, the association seems to behave as a rule. I didn't see any example or reference to this behavior in the [ReplaceAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (/.) documentation.  Is this undocumented? Is it OK to rely on this behavior?

While it may not make sense to use this for new code. It can be useful for simplifying to work needed to adapt old code to using associations.

Comment: There might be differences in the case of repeated left hand sides.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I described this use in [Is there a faster way to Map an Association?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55980/121) and it is documented in the 
[Mathematica Quick Revision History](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html) for 10.0.2, though as noted in my self-answer it existed in 10.0.0 as well:

> - [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html), [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html), and [`ReplacePart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html) now work with Associations

Why these things are not more directly documented is a mystery, and rather frustrating, as one must guess what is and is not overloaded to work with `Association` and if that support is official and lasting or transient.  See the answers to my similar question:

- [Listable functions thread over Associations; is this documented?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63293/121)

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, we did finally document it, probably in 10.4 or thereabouts.

Note that the bullet point in 10.0.2 references to the fact that `_Association /. rules_` began to work, not that you could use an Assocation in the 2nd argument.  You could always do that.  That it wasn't documented as largely an oversite.  But there is also an issue (which is explictly documented under Possible Issues).  In an association, keys are effectively wrapped in Verbatim.  This isn't typically an issue, as the normal purpose of an association is to index literal keys, but it is a difference between `expr /. _Association` and `expr /. Normal[_Association]`.

Answer (score 4):

Compare results

```
x /. <|x -> 123, x -> 456|>
```

> 456

versus

```
x /. {x -> 123, x -> 456}
```

> 123

It seems associations are being operated on similar to `KeyValueMap[Rule]@Join@` before `ReplaceAll`.  I would expect this behaviour considering how associations handle duplicate keys and how `ReplaceAll` processes a list of rules on a pattern match.

Comment: There is no such thing as: `<|x -> 123, x -> 456|>`, it exists only if you hold it, it automatically merges with latest key values, so to `<|x -> 456|>`.

Answer (score 1):

`Normal` converts an `Association` to a list of rules.

```
Normal[<|x -> 123, y -> 456|>]
```

> {x -> 123, y -> 456}

but evidently will evaluate the argument first:

```
Normal[<|x -> 123, x -> 456|>]
```

> {x -> 456}